# Is streaming youtube videos on background legal?

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am building an browser that would eneble users to browse and stream  youtube videos / any web page and this app would even continue fetching even when phone is locked. This app would work on background and user can perform his other task on foreground as well. So are there any rules that i are being defied here? Remember that this app is not meant only for youtube.
Edit 1 : if there are any ways by which i could get through then please do suggest. I've seen some apps on playstore that downloads video from every site ( including youtube and most users use it for youtube only) and this app are still there.

Edit 2 : So can i do 1 thing : I upload my app that follows all guidelines and wont open any youtube links. If a user tries to open youtube link then ill display an message: "due to youtube terms and condition this app cant play youtube video  but there's another app at LINK that can open this kind of videos. Ill host this app at some other place. Is this Ok to do? Will they not block my app if i do this?

Comment: What I can say with my experience is you can't even a create an app where you have all youtube video's in it. I can't update my app based on the Youtube Terms of Service. They say I have a background play and that isn't true. I just placed Iframes of youtube video's in my app. So I would suggets load any youtube video's in the youtube app instead.

Comment: So can i do 1 thing : I upload my app that follows all guidelines and wont open any youtube links. If a user tries to open youtube link then ill display an message: "due to youtube terms and condition this app cant play youtube video  but there's another app at LINK that can open this kind of videos. Ill host this app at some other place. Is this Ok to do?

Comment: What you can do is let the link in the app but when you click on the link let it open in the youtube then would you have no problems

Answer (score 1):

Based on Youtube Terms of Service, it's forbid .. you can read about that here https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

**Number 5.L**

*you agree not to access Content or any reason other than your personal, non-commercial use solely as intended through and permitted by the normal functionality of the Service, and solely for Streaming. "Streaming" means a contemporaneous digital transmission of the material by YouTube via the Internet to a user operated Internet enabled device in such a manner that the data is intended for real-time viewing and not intended to be downloaded (either permanently or temporarily), copied, stored, or redistributed by the user.*

Because official youtube apps not allowing you to play video on locked screen, so every app that use youtube service is not allowed too

Comment: Yes but there are apps that provides downloading youtube videos. And this app is not (just) intended for youtube.So can i get this app passed highlight this fact? I can take acknowledgement of users that they wont do any kind of stuff if they do then it would be on their own risk. Is this ok? If anyone has some kind of solution or something then please do inform me . I've invested lot of time on this app

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe this seems like it would be a breach of the YouTube [Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=GB&template=terms), **Section 5 - C**.

> you agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Website itself, the YouTube Player, or such other means as YouTube may explicitly designate for this purpose

I am not 100% sure what the ramifications (legal or otherwise) of breaking this would be, however it is likely YouTube would not let your service exist for long.

*Note: I am not a lawyer*

Comment: Yes but there are apps that provides downloading youtube videos. And this app is not (just) intended for youtube.So can i get this app passed highlight this fact? I can take acknowledgement of users that they wont do any kind of stuff if they do then it would be on their own risk. Is this ok? If anyone has some kind of solution or something then please do inform me . I've invested lot of time on this app

Comment: Unless you have been explicitly granted permission by YouTube (which you could try to get) - any breach of the *T.O.S* will probably result in your service being blocked. As indicated in **Section 11.3 - A**. So I suggest you contact them, explain your service, and seek an exception from certain elements of the T.O.S

Comment: I had asked them lets see. If not then can i do this thing : I upload my app that follows all guidelines and wont open any youtube links. If a user tries to open youtube link then ill display an message: "due to youtube terms and condition this app cant play youtube video  but there's another app at LINK that can open this kind of videos. Ill host this app at some other place. Is this Ok to do?